# A 16GB file with 1204 extents. Is it normal?

Tags: virtualbox, files, disk

I noticed slow disk performance running a VM in VirtualBox.

Filefrag shows 1204 extends for the virtual disk file.

I know file fragmentation only occurs when necessary, but i wondering if this is a correct value or if the file needs some kind of defrag.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is a dynamically allocated image, in which case it may grow in size over time and this may explain the many different extents you have for this file.

Comment: the vdi file is not dynamically allocated